# React Native slice() function undefined error

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-listview

I want to update my listview row for that I am trying to slice listview datasource but its raising below error:

> this.state.dataSource.slice is not a function. (In
>   'this.state.dataSource.slice()', 'this.state.dataSource.slice' is
>   undefined)

And here is my code:

```
let newArray = this.state.dataSource.slice();
newArray[indexToUpdate] = {
  //Here I am updating my values.
};
this.setState({
  dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray),
});
```

Let me know if there is any error in my code or something wrong I have done.

Comment: @trevor but I have seen most of the examples and links related with updating listview.I have get this common approach like using slice() method. **What is the reason then I am unable to use slice() method or its undefined for my dataSource object?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.state.dataSource` is not an Array, that's why you cant do `slice()` on dataSource. It looks like this

```
{ _rowHasChanged: [Function: rowHasChanged],
  _getRowData: [Function: defaultGetRowData],
  _sectionHeaderHasChanged: [Function],
  _getSectionHeaderData: [Function: defaultGetSectionHeaderData],
  _dataBlob: { s1: [ 'row 1', 'row 2' ] },
  _dirtyRows: [ [ true, true ] ],
  _dirtySections: [ true ],
  _cachedRowCount: 2,
  rowIdentities: [ [ '0', '1' ] ],
  sectionIdentities: [ 's1' ] 
}
```

Your required array is in `_dataBlob` key of that object.

**Note:** it's working fine and updates listview dataSource using below line

```
this.state.dataSource._dataBlob.s1.slice()
```

Comment: Let me print my dataSource object.

Comment: So I need to call like this, **this.state.dataSource._dataBlob.slice()**  Right??

Comment: you may need to call it as this.state.dataSource._dataBlob.s1.slice()
s1,s2 represents sections. You can refer this for details http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/listviewdatasource.html#clonewithrowsandsections